# react-native-linear-gradient - TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.requireNativeComponent) is not a function

Tags: react-native, ts-jest

When running my Jest test on a UI component that uses react-native-linear-gradient, I get the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

 TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.requireNativeComponent) is not a function

    > 4 | import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
        | ^
```

I am guessing that maybe I need to mock it but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following Github forum talking about [this exact issue here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2006).

The solution is to add to the top of your jest test file after the imports the following:

```
jest.mock('react-native-linear-gradient', () => 'LinearGradient');
```